# How to securely set up your website allow an Android app to be logged in forever

Tags: android, django, session-timeout, api-key

I'm on a team that has a website created with Django. We're starting on making an Android app. We are somewhat stuck on a couple questions related to how to properly handle authentication. I'll address one of them here:

We are running on the assumption that a user is going to expect to not have to log into a mobile app more than once ever, under normal circumstances. For instance, on my Android device, I haven't logged into my Google app for maybe a year, or my Trello app for months.

If we use Django's usual session system, and the user stops using the app for a sufficient amount of time, the user will be logged out. We could have an API key that the app uses to authenticate with the website, which can be used to log in instead of a password, and then establish a new session key. However, it sounds like you want to renew API keys periodically as well, which seems to present the same problem all over again.

Since this is a security issue, we don't want to rely on instincts or plausible solutions. We know it's an esoteric field. We want to make sure we know what the right way to go about this is.

So, here are some possible ways we've considered, with possible drawbacks:

---

#### Make a session renewal request once a day in the background.

This requires a background service, which may put off users by confusing them, or using more power than they'd like. A lot of our users may be in areas of the world with low access to Internet connectivity and not want to have background processes making requests for no reason.

#### Use an API key, expire it, but still allow renewal after an arbitrary amount of time.

If a user comes back after 5 months, allow them to use the old API key, one time, only to generate a new API key. This is similar to password expiration policies. However, if an API key operates on the same assumptions as a session key, this seems to not follow the proper policy.

#### Use Google's Cloud Messaging System to periodically send them new keys

Let Google deal with the hard stuff. Admittedly somewhat out of left field.

#### Implement an Oauth2 provider

Seems like overkill, but maybe? It seems that the refresh_token/access_token system is the sort of thing I'm looking for.

---

One factor I will put as a footnote, because I don't want to distract from the main point with an independent question, but which may be more interdependent than I assume: For V1 of our app, we will rely a lot on Web Views, but still have some direct API calls. We are faced with the question of how to coordinate authentication between the API calls and the Web View. Initially we thought we'd have to coordinate authentication between an API key for the API calls, and a session for the web views, but from reading other Stackoverflow responses, it sounds like I can just share session cookies between the two, though I haven't confirmed this yet.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the method described in [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) :

- Implement your view and retrieve your user details
- Manually specify the authentication backend.
- Login your user using login(request, user)

The code looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def your_view(request):

    // retrieve your user
    ...

    // you can write your own backend to do lots of things
    user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'

    login(request, user)
```

Comment: Thanks, that will be useful for me. However it doesn't answer the fundamental question I have here, which is how to set up a secure paradigm on a mobile device that doesn't require the user to enter a password more than once, under normal circumstances. To be clear, this question is more about sessions cookies and tokens than it is about Django and Andoid.